# excel autonumber 1.a , 1.b, 1.c

Tags: microsoft-excel

in an excel sheet. 
we generally give serial number as 1 , 2 , 3
if i want to give subparts to 1 
i am thinking of giving 1.a, 1.b, 1.c

normally for the case of 1, 2, 3, - i would pull down using the mouse button for autonumbering.

how to autonumber for the case of 
1.a, 1.b, 1.c

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

autonumbering only works for numbers...

You could try the following, but most probably this would lead you too far:

```
- Enter 97 (ascii value for 'a') in B1 and 98 in B2, and pull down
- CONCATENATE("1."; CHAR(B1)) in C1 and pull down
```

now you will see 1.a in C1 and 1.b, 1.c, ...

Comment: Yea, and '65' for 'A' and so on.... but really this should be question for SU :)